# jquery each function not working on client click asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
function AddressVal5() {
   $('.ma-addressEdit .address:visible input:text.number').each(function () {
      var maxLength = $(this).attr('maxLength');
      var thisLength = $(this).val().length;
      //  alert(maxLength + ' ' + thisLength)
      //$(this).next('.error').hide();
      if ($(this).val() == '' || thisLength < maxLength) {
         alert("sa");
         $(this).next('.error').show();
         return false;
      }
   });

   $('.ma-addressEdit .address:visible input:text, .ma-addressEdit .address:visible textarea').each(function () {
      var maxLength = $(this).attr('maxLength');
      var thisLength = $(this).val().length;
      $(this).next('.error').hide();
      if ($(this).val() == '' || thisLength < maxLength) {
         $(this).next('.error').show();
      }
   });

}
```

I am working on jquery validations its work properly with

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="clear" id="addressUpdateBtn"><img src="images/update.png" width="83" height="31" alt="Upate" onclick="AddressVal5()" /></a>
```

but not work with

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnNewADD" runat="server"
                                ImageUrl="~/_layouts/images/Experia/update.png" CssClass="Nbutton" OnClientClick="return AddressVal5();" ToolTip="Add" OnClick="imgbtnNewADD_Click" />
```

error messages are come but refresh on click please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly that is because you have no `return false;` in second `each` statement.

**EDIT:** Oops. So simple! Your are doing `return` from each callback function and not from AddressVal5. You should have something like

```
function AddressVal5() {
   var isValid = true;
   $('.ma-addressEdit .address:visible input:text.number').each(function () {
      var maxLength = $(this).attr('maxLength');
      var thisLength = $(this).val().length;
      //  alert(maxLength + ' ' + thisLength)
      //$(this).next('.error').hide();
      if ($(this).val() == '' || thisLength < maxLength) {
         alert("sa");
         $(this).next('.error').show();
         isValid = false;
         return false;
      }
   });

   $('.ma-addressEdit .address:visible input:text, .ma-addressEdit .address:visible textarea').each(function () {
      var maxLength = $(this).attr('maxLength');
      var thisLength = $(this).val().length;
      $(this).next('.error').hide();
      if ($(this).val() == '' || thisLength < maxLength) {
         $(this).next('.error').show();
         isValid = false;
         return false;
      }
   });
   return isValid;
}
```

to make it work. In first case it worked fine because there is no submit button.